# How can I fix this terminal error?

Tags: command-line, 16.04

Whenever I open a terminal, my terminal displays this:

```
No command 'mask' found, did you mean:
Command 'mawk' from package 'mawk' (main)
Command 'task' from package 'taskwarrior' (universe)
Command 'ask' from package 'ask' (universe)
Command 'mark' from package 'mailutils-mh' (universe)
Command 'mark' from package 'nmh' (universe)
```

The output of `grep "mask" ~/.bashrc` is

> mask 022 umask 022

What is the problem with my system and how can I solve it?

Comment: What do you want to do? It looks like you're trying to run `mask` command, but you didn't install the proper package. Can you tell us what this is for?

Comment: i don't know. it runs once i open a terminal

Comment: Sounds like you have a "mask" command in your .bashrc (a file that is "sourced" every time you open the terminal).
Run `grep "mask" ~/.bashrc` and show us the output

Comment: mask 022
umask 022

Answer (score 3):

If you got this problem every time when you open a terminal, please check the ~/.bashrc and the /etc/profile files. Search for string "mask" in these files.

As [RoVo](https://askubuntu.com/users/631600/rovo) suggested here, you can run `grep "mask" ~/.bashrc /etc/profile` first to see where the "mask" command was written.

If you can find the string "mask", you can just remove it or put a "#" in the begining of the line to comment it out. (If it's not being used anymore)

Note: you will need root privilege to edit the /etc/profile file, which can be achieved with `gksudo gedit /etc/profile`

Comment: If he issues `grep -n "mask" ~/.bashrc` and `grep -n "mask" /etc/profile` before opening and searching, it would be easier to find and be sure.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but if it's not working and the OP does not know what that for, I think it's harmless to comment it out.

Comment: sure it is, it's not working anyway ;-) But I mean, it would be easier to find for the Op if he knows which file and which line number before opening ... and afterwards follow your advice.

Comment: There are a number of files where this could be. Try `grep -H mask ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2> /dev/null`